# how to calculate the scatter within classes for a 50x20 matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am trying to reduce a largely dimentional matrix to only 2D, i was using an example for 2D arrays,which works, but i would need to do the same for a higher dimentional scatter. I have two classes and each classes have matrices of 50x20 dimensional feature spaces.

For my example i have these 2D arrays:

```
rectangles = np.array([[1,1.5,1.7,1.45,1.1,1.6,1.8],[1.8,1.55,1.45,1.6,1.65,1.7,1.75]])
triangles = np.array([[0.1,0.5,0.25,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.35,0.15,0.4,0.5,0.48],[1.1,1.5,1.3,1.2,1.15,1.0,1.4,1.2,1.3,1.5,1.0]])
```

Afterwards im finding the mean for both classes triangles and rectangles

```
# Calculate the mean vectors per class
mean_rectangles = np.mean(rectangles,axis=1).reshape(2,1)
    
mean_triangles = np.mean(triangles,axis=1).reshape(2,1)
```

The value given by the means of classes rectangle and triangles, i use them to calculate  the scatter:

```
scatter_triangles = np.dot((triangles-mean_triangles),(triangles-mean_triangles).T)
scatter_circles = np.dot((circles-mean_circles),(circles-mean_circles).T)

# Calculate the SW by adding the scatters within classes 
SW = scatter_triangles+scatter_circles+scatter_rectangles
print(SW)


plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to know how would i find the scatter within classes and plot them, exactly the same way but for a larger data, precisely for a 50x20 matrix?

For reproducibility this is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

# Create data
c_A_array = [[ 31,  25,  17,  62,  26,  23, 193, 143,  37,  29, 220, 216, 175, 195, 207, 198, 190, 222, 178, 214],
 [ 31,  26,  19,  59,  25,  23, 193, 140,  37,  29, 220, 216, 174, 195, 207, 198, 190, 220, 178, 214],
 [ 31,  23,  17,  67,  23,  22, 195, 147,  38,  31, 222, 215, 182, 195, 213, 198, 185, 221, 178, 207],
 [ 31,  23,  19,  67,  23,  23, 194, 144,  37,  31, 222, 218, 179, 198, 216, 198, 186, 221, 179, 207],
 [ 31,  28,  17,  65,  23,  22, 193, 142,  36,  31, 222, 217, 177, 195, 216, 196, 182, 220, 174, 207]]

c_B_array = [[ 16,  24,  33,  43,  43,  58, 163,  76,  57, 105, 205, 200, 193, 188, 186, 193, 182, 227, 193, 227],
 [  9,  13,  22,  36,  13,  49, 163,  39,  33, 105, 204, 200, 193, 191, 188, 193, 183, 224, 194, 227],
 [ 23,  17,  10,  28,  21,  40, 166,  46,  28, 102, 208, 206, 196, 198, 195, 202, 190, 225, 196, 229],
 [ 25,  19,  11,  30,  23,  39, 166,  46,  26,  99, 208, 206, 199, 196, 198, 201, 189, 227, 198, 231],
 [ 25,  20,  12,  31,  25,  40, 169,  48,  27, 101, 211, 206, 198, 198, 196, 202, 190, 226, 198, 229]]

#Plot the data
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax0.scatter(c_A_array[0],c_A_array[1],marker='s',c='grey',edgecolor='black')
ax0.scatter(c_B_array[0],c_B_array[1],marker='o',c='blue',edgecolor='black')




# Calculate the mean vectors per class
c_A_array_mean = np.mean(c_A_array,axis=1)
c_B_array_mean = np.mean(c_A_array,axis=1)

# Calculate the scatter matrices for the SW (Scatter within) and sum the elements up

scatter_c_A_array = np.dot((c_A_array-c_A_array_mean),(c_A_array-c_A_array_mean).T)
scatter_c_B_array = np.dot((c_B_array-c_B_array_mean),(c_B_array-c_B_array_mean).T)

# Calculate the SW by adding the scatters within classes 
SW = scatter_c_A_array+scatter_c_B_array
print(SW)


plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
> (5,20) (5,)

Comment: When you execute `c_A_array-c_A_array_mean` do you intend to subtract the mean to each item in the list, for each of the 5 lists?

Comment: Yes, each list is a cluster and to find the the within scatter of each class, i need the mean of the cluster and subtract from each point inside my cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy doesnt broadcast array to columns unfortunaltely.
Try:

```
(np.array(c_A_array).T-c_A_array_mean).T
```

For all the subtractions.

This works too tried both of them, guess the second is faster:

```
np.array(c_A_array)-c_A_array_mean.reshape((5,1))
```

Comment: np.dot((c_A_array-np.array([c_A_array_mean])),(c_A_array-np.array([c_A_array_mean])).T) for c_B aswell gives:  ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,20) (1,5)

Comment: I assume the first transposition is a typo?

Comment: No it's not, both the yield the same output.

Comment: Numpy broadcasting rules: what happens in the first one is we transpose the matrix to (20,5) and the mean array is (5,). So numpy broadcast the mean array matching the dimensions from right to left. So internally it operates as thought the mean array was (20,5) too. When the subtractions is done we transpose back to (5,20). This doesnt work in your code because numpy matches shape right to left. However in the second case we reshape the mean array to a 2d array of shape (5,1). Which can be matched to (5,20). You definetely should read up on broadcasting rules:

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html